# Upload files to a specific folder on Onedrive in web application

Tags: c#, onedrive

I want to upload files to a specific folder on my onedrive using C# in web application. I am not able to find any sdk for that. All i can find is sdk for windows phone application. Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [OneDrive SDK](https://github.com/onedrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp) is still valid for use in any .NET language/platform, including ASP.NET.

For web-based applications, you'll need to handle authentication yourself though. Because of the various ways of authentication a web app, the SDK didn't provide a prescriptive authentication solution for web apps.

You can either code the OAuth 2 implementation or use an existing library to connect it up (like using OWIN). Once you have an access token for OneDrive, you can provide the token to the SDK and then use the SDK as normal.

The [webhook sample project](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-webhooks-aspnet) in the OneDrive org has an example of how to provide an access token directly to the OneDrive SDK by way of creating a [OneDriveAccountServiceProvider](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-webhooks-aspnet/blob/master/OneDriveWebhooks/Models/OneDriveAccountServiceProvider.cs).